# Move gameObject Point A to Point B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm confronted with a problem with the implementation of enemies. I have a gameobject for an enemy with box collider and basically all I need. Now I need to implement a basic enemy AI walking by default if there is nobody. So i created a coroutine :

```
IEnumerator MoveByDefault()
{
    animationComponent.Play("walk");
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 10f);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 10f);
}
```

The code above moves the enemies but it's really fast, and I want the gameObject to walk slowly like if the enemy walks from point A to point B. How can I do that ?

Comment: you mean fast like it disapears from one point and appears in the other?

Comment: Yes that's exactly !

Comment: Take a look at this answer...it may provide some help...http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14288/can-someone-explain-how-using-timedeltatime-as-t-i.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the coroutine to update the transform.position every frame. You also need to calculate your percentage of completion of the sequence and pass it in to the lerp function. Have a look at this Q&A from Unity Answers: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/192438/coroutines-and-lerp-how-to-make-them-friends.html